# Ver las conexiones al servirdor sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy utilizando la siguiente consulta para ver las direccionnes ip que se conectan a sql server pero solo me muestra lo de los ultimos tres días ¿Hay alguna forma de ver todos los equipos que se conectaron por ultima vez el mes pasado?

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
```

Comment: Nada en la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-connections-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) de la tabla menciona ese límite. Tampoco se ve en otras preguntas o en usos sugeridos de los datos en ella. ¿No será que reiniciaste el servidor hace 3 días?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dm_exec_connections` no te muestra las conexiones de X cantidad de tiempo, te muestra las conexiones que **actualmente existen** a la base de datos.

Si quieres poder consultar las conexiones históricas, tienes básicamente dos opciones:

- Activas la [auditoria de *logins*](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/ssms/configure-login-auditing-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver15) a nivel de la instancia del SQL Server, en el Management Studio, selecciona la instancia que te interesa, botón derecho, propiedades, ve a *security* y selecciona el nivel que te interesa en *Login auditing*. Esta información queda en el Event Log del servidor.
- Escribes un [trigger `for logon`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/triggers/logon-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15) en la instancia de tu interés y vas llenando una tabla de auditoría con la información que te pueda interesar registrar. OJO, que en este caso, solamente podrás registrar información de los inicios de sesión exitosos, no de los fallidos, pues en ese caso no se dispara ningún trigger.